# IPA Re-packaging while changing the bundle-id

Tags: ios, xcode

### Environment

- iOS 8.4
- xcode 6.4
- OS-X @ Yosemite

### Use-case

- An existing App for which:

  - The source code is not available
  - FairPlay doesn't apply ( not DRM protected )
- Change the "bundle id" in the IPA ( at plist files such as 'info.plists' )
- Re-package using developer certificates, new bundle-id and a provisioning profile
- Run on provisioned devices

### Question

Having in mind that the source-code is not available and the app cannot be re-compiled, Can the bundle-id be changed in the above mentioned manner? would it have any side-affects?

Answer (score 0):

Oh sure can change `Bundle-ID` without the IPA having any issues. Just make sure that your bundle ID's last word is exactly what it was before. For example:

**Original**:`com.abcd.aName`

**Can be**:`com.efgh.aName`

See the **aName**? That should be same. That is what the IPA's original ID was. Good luck.